# What should i know before start working with project Tango Dev Kit

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

i got the opportunity as an intern to work with Project Tango. I have some Android and Java experience but at the moment i don't see any light at the end of the tunnel. I look at the sample code and i get used it a bit, but somehow i think i miss some major parts to work with Project Tango. I never worked with OpenGl oder any other 3D Engine. Because Project Tango is very new there are no tutorial how to somestuff with it.

I would be happy to get some tipps which knowledge i should have to work the Tango efficient. At the moment just i copy just some code from one sample project to an other project an tinker something that barely works. Some Tipps what i should learn first before start with the Tango would be awesome!!!

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

this is a really broad question, I think the best way to start is having a idea in mind. You should find out what you want to build first, and then find out the tools/APIs to achieve that.

In term of the APIs, Java is probably the easier one for you to start, but you will need to find a 3D graphic render engine to use, if you want to develop 3D graphic content. [Java sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java)

Tango also has Unity integration, Unity is a popular game engine. Tango has full supported API and [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) for Unity, so that's a good start point as well. If you search Unity tutorial, there are tons of them online, introducing basic Unity development.